# Where are aspx.cs and aspx.designer.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, decompiling, decompiler

I have inherented a web site from someone who is not available any more.  In the deployed folder I have Config.aspx there (please see the code).  But I can not find the codebehind file.  The config page works.  Where can I find the .cs files?

Thanks

```
<%@ page language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Master/StaffPortal.master" autoeventwireup="true"
    inherits="Admin_Config" title="Configuration" codebehind="Config.aspx.cs" %>

<asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="PageBody" runat="Server">
    <div style="width: 405px; height: 25px" class="GeneralCaption">
    Configuration Parameters
    </div>
    <asp:Table ID="Table" runat="server" Style="width:100%">
    </asp:Table>
    <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" CssClass="GeneralButton" Text="OK" OnClick="OKButton_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CssClass="GeneralButton" Text="Cancel" OnClick="CancelButton_Click" />
</asp:content>
```

Comment: Have you tried right-click and View Code in the designer?

Comment: maybe it is the result of a precompiled web site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cant find them anywhere and you need to get the cs files out of the DLL - here's how:

Get Reflector by redgate, install this add-in: http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx

Drag the DLL into Reflector then dissemble it using Denis's add-in. All the code behind files will be extracted from the DLL, unfortunately comments will be missing.

**UPDATE**

These days I use the free tool [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and you can simply save assemblies as projects - its a great way to convert entire projects to different languages.

Answer (score 8):

if the project is **deployed** then all .cs files are already compiled into .dll file in bin folder.
You need to have the project source to access them.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the published folder, the codebehind pages would have been compiled into a .dll in the bin folder. The only way to get the code behind would be to get the source project

Comment: an fyi you can get the code behind unless the DLL is obfuscated or (remote soft) salamander'd.

Comment: @jeremy thompson, i know you can use reflector for this but there is no guarantee that the code wasn't obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

When we publish a web application, the code behind files are compiled into `dll's` that are stored in a bin folder.

You have to get the Source files from the Developer.